# Unknown syntax. Property? Method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I never saw this code.

```
Klase schoolclass = new schoolclass();
String surname = schoolclass.Best.Surname;
```

I know that `Surname` is probably property. But what is `Best`? Can someone give me example of class `Klase`?

Thank you.

Comment: I think there will be very few who could do that (basically only you or whoever wrote this class) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a property or field of the object `Best` in the `Schoolclass` class.

Example:

```
public class Schoolclass
{
   public Person Best {get;set;}       
}


public class Person
{    
   public string Surname {get;set;}    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Already found the answer myself. Probably still sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

`Klase` seems to be a custom class, so we have no way of telling you what `Best` for sure, but it might either be a **field** or a **property**.

And you can use another field/property `Surname` on it's result, because it must return class/struct that has `Surname` property.